# tmutil fails to show the local snapshots on my computer

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine

I typed

```
sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

in terminal and entered the password. However, nothing happened. I suppose `tmutil` to return all local snapshots on my computer, but it only returns `xxxs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ xxx$`.

Does that mean there is no local snapshots in my computer? I don't believe it. My Mac has updated to High Sierra and my external hard drive fails to backup because Time Machine could not create a local snapshot.

Comment: Why don't you believe there are no local snapshots? Do you have any located here: `/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/`

Comment: I have similar issue & also when I use the command 'sudo tmutil snapshot' I get an error saying system failed to create local snapshot. I updated from Sierra to High Sierra on cloned external ssd....might this have created the relevant issues?

Comment: @Nigel Hi there, probably there are really no local snapshots LOL. I discovered that there was a file of photos which occupied 30GB of my laptop storage. I backed them up and deleted them and my computer is fine now.